# Is it possible to add button to Excel chart customization buttons?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, customization, add-in

I have created a custom VSTO add-in that helps to format charts according to company design guidelines. When a chart is selected a custom task pane pops-up.

However, it is not always necessary to show the task pane. Instead I would like to add a button to the "Chart customization buttons" (the three buttons next to the upper right corner of any chart from Excel 2013 and onwards, see image below). The function of the button would be to show the task pane.

Does anybody know if that is possible?

[image]